# jpa without container

Tags: java, orm, jpa, console-application

I like to use jpa, but without application container.
I intend it to use it in console application.

Is there any example ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JPA in a Java SE environmenet. Here are some examples:

- [Java Persistence APIs in Java SE - GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/persistence/persistence-example.html).
- [Employee Examples using EclipseLink ORM.XML](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EmployeeXML).
- [Persistence tutorial: JPA and Java SE with Netbeans](http://www.1001-computer.de/persistence-tutorial-jpa-javase-netbeans/?lang=en).

Answer (score 3):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/